# How to choose values log-uniformly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

I have read a text in which a discrete value is chosen at random log-uniformly between 128 and 4000 and a second continuous value is chosen at random log-uniformly between 0.001 and 1.

How can I do this in Matlab?

Second, what is the property of log-uniformly instead of just uniform? I assume that choosing log-uniform values between 128 and 4000 favors values near 128 while uniform makes all values equal likely but I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: @Adriaan But this will not produce random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a base and convert your interval to that base then generate random numbers and convert it back. Here is an example with default distribution and base 10

```
x = log10([128 4000])
r = 10.^(x(1) + (x(2)-x(1)).*rand(100,1));
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. So let's say my interval [1,100]. Does this log-uniformly generated random number mean that the values near the left boundary are more likely?

Comment: @machinery Think of your example as an interval between [0,2]. And we generate random numbers. Then if I raise each element to the powers of ten...?